# Is it possible to create uniform columns in individual/separate html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a list which is a html container (div) and lists the list items (divs) inside them as individual panels, but I'd like the list to be uniform, so the columns inside the panels should line up, like on this picture:

[image: Example of html structure]

As it is visible, `Col_1` has width of `"BBBBB"` because that is the most wide content in that column, `Col_2` has width of `"0x12345678"`, etc...

I haven't find any css that is able to work as a grid or table outside its parent, and since all list item container is a parent of the "grid", they couldn't be synchronized.

I've been trying creating a javascript to search for each column element, pick the widest and set the width to all other elements in the column, assigned this method to each element's `DOMSubtreeModified` event and assigned the elements to `ResizeObserver`.

It worked fairly well, but since this list is dynamically generated, appending each item to the DOM tree triggered the resize event, which is not really good. I've tried disabling my resize method while generating the list and enabling it only after the list is appended to the DOM as a whole, but then each item called the ResizeObserver event at once. Even if calling it from `requestAnimationFrame(() => { ... });` after all items are appended and filled with content, which supposed to happen only after all items are visible, and their content isn't changing, all items are triggering the ResizeObserver, because their size have been changed.

Javascript is something like this:

```
// This is called only once on init
var resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (var entry of entries) {
        var elem = $(entry.target);
        console.log("Elem resized", elem);
        // I should call the resizeColumn() here
    }
});


// The following code is called every time when the list data arrives to listData variable
var listPanel = $("#listPanel");

listData.forEach((entry) => {
    listPanel.append(createListEntry(entry)); // createListEntry() function creates an list item with content
});

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    listPanel.find("[col-group='Col_1']").each((key, elem) => {
        resizeObserver.observe(elem); // for some reason this triggers the callback immediately
    });
});

resizeColumn("Col_1"); // this should make uniform columns for Col_1 only after showing the list,
                       // but the ResizeObserver calls this function as many times as many items
                       // I have in the list
```

I really would love to solve this problem with pure html/css, but I don't know what kind of solution exists for this issue.

I'd like to avoid min-width/max-width type of solutions, because the content is dynamic, and should use the space the most optimal way.

If there is no pure html/css solution, then how should I modify my javascript, to not to trigger the ResizeObserver on showing the items?

---------------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------------

This is the closest I could get, but since the `listItem` class sets `display: contents` I can not make it have background, border or any style, since it is not a box anymore. If I could have an element for each line that I can add styles to, that would be perfect. Down in the comments `subgrid` was recommended, that would be the best for this job, unfortunately not supported, only by Firefox.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #121212;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.listContainer {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto 1fr;  
}

.listItem {
  display: contents;
  background: #45729a;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.listCell {
  background: #ef4536;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="listContainer">
  
  <div class="listItem">
    <div class="listCell">AAA</div>
    <div class="listCell">0x00001</div>
    <div class="listCell">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="listCell">true</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="listItem">
    <div class="listCell">BBBBB</div>
    <div class="listCell">0x00</div>
    <div class="listCell">bbbbbb</div>
    <div class="listCell">false</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="listItem">
    <div class="listCell">C</div>
    <div class="listCell">0x12345678</div>
    <div class="listCell">ccc</div>
    <div class="listCell">true</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Does the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout do what you're looking to accomplish, or is your use case something more unusual?

Comment: I've tried using `table`, or `display: table`, and `css grid` and `flex grid`, none of them worked, because if you check the image I attached the list item should be the grid element, but there are individual list items, so I'd have different grids for each item, I don't believe multiple grids can be synchronized, even though the layout is the same.

Comment: Natively with `subgrid` but it has very little implementation at the moment (only Firefox). Othwerwise, JS is the answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Yes, `subgrid` is exactly what I need, I just didn't know it exists. Now I was searching, but I don't find any workaround or polyfill to make it work on other browsers. That is very unfortunate. At least I know what to search for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do that will be, set the class name same for all the elements whose width you want to set same. Then in js get them, compare their widths and then set the maximum one as width of each element.

```
var heights = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.col_1').forEach(col => {
    heights.push(col.offsetHeight);
})
```

Then use some basic algorithm to compare the elements of the `heights` list and then set the maximum value as everyone's height.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.col_1').forEach(col => {
    col.offsetHeight = 'that_max_value';
})
```

Comment: My `resizeColumn("Col_1")` call does basically this. Not the resizing is the problem. The problem is I can't make this method called only after all items are shown. I have to attach each element to the ResizeObserver, because their content may change and then resizing must be called, and ResizeObserver calls the method many times even after all items are visible. Your solution is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: If it is syncrounous, you can use window.onload

Comment: It is asynchronous, and happening indefinite times after page load.

Comment: Then you can probably trigger the function when the value changes by using the onchange attr.

Comment: Yes, but there are situations when the content does not change, but the size does, like when you resize the browser, or change the style of the content, etc. These changes don't trigger the change events, but the resizeobserver can tell me the cell size changed. I'm still fighting with the events. The real solution would not be using javascript to fix this issue. Look at my edited question.